# Clip path circle small gap issue

Tags: css

I have a page transition but when going from a white page to a black page, the circle clip path creates a small gap, as seen on the screenshot.

Meanwhile here is a demo https://elk-sand.vercel.app/. It happens when going from the home page to transformeren page from the navigation.

Another demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-dirac-r000oy?file=/src/App.js

screenshot issue:

[image: circle with small gap bug]

Funny how this question is being closed for not providing code while their is a code sandbox, so here you go for the ones who prefer it here:

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    clip-path: circle(0%);
  }
  to {
    clip-path: circle(50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div
  style="
    height: 100vh;
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    inset: 0px;
    animation: mymove 20s infinite;
  "
  className="App"
>
  <div
    style="
      position: fixed;
      inset: 0px;
      background: yellow;
      animation: mymove 20s infinite;
    "
  ></div>
</div>
```

The issue is a red border around the yellow circle, which should not be there.

Comment: Post the code so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I provided a codesandbox when posting the question.

Comment: There is no way to isolate the circle clip path and show only this in a snippet here?

Comment: I cannot provide the whole code of the transition in a snippet. I created a minimal sandbox so others can fork it and play with it and maybe solve it. Might solve it myself since I'm working on it right now. Couldn't find a post related to this issue. Since it only happens when 2 circles are animating in each other.

Comment: Solved it, unfortunately, I cannot post the answer since this issue is being closed.

Comment: I already voted for reopening after you posted the code. Just a little advice for future questions: It is expected to post some code to the question itself, not everyone has the time to look at an external source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigating, I found out it was due to a small scale from 105% to 100% and the clip-path circle which was getting bigger.

Adding translate-z did not solve this issue, unfortunately. I removed the small scale since it didn't add that much effect.

To fix the example that I sent is easy to solve just add 1% to the highest element circle path or set a delay on the first element.

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    clip-path: circle(0%);
  }
  to {
    clip-path: circle(50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div
  style="
    height: 100vh;
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    inset: 0px;
    animation: mymove 20s infinite;
    animation-delay: 0.05s;
  "
  className="App"
>
  <div
    style="
      position: fixed;
      inset: 0px;
      background: yellow;
      animation: mymove 20s infinite;
    "
  ></div>
</div>
```